# Eloquent: How do I assign values to guarded columns while using the create() method?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Let's say I have an endpoint for user submitted forms. The form input will be stored as a JSON object in a column of a database table, and the user ID will be stored in another. Because I don't want users to be able to somehow set any user ID they want, I've left the user_id column out of the $fillable variable of the Eloquent model.

The create() method accepts an array of key/value pairs to be assigned, but will only assign values to fillable columns. How do I add the user's ID to the guarded user_id column at the same time? Do I have to fetch the last row and update the user ID as a second operation?

Thanks for all help, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

IF you don't have attribute in `$fillable` it doesn't mean you cannot fill it.

The `$fillable` property holds the attributes that could be filled using `create()` or `fill()` method but you can still set value for any attributes using property access.

So let's assume you have Model with `email`, `something` and `else` properties. You set `$fillable` like so:

```
protected $fillable = ['email', 'something'];
```

Now let's assume you have data like this:

```
$data = [
  'email' => 'sample@example.com',
  'something' => 'foo',
  'else' => 'bar',
];
```

so now when you use:

```
Model::create($data);
```

you will have filled only `email` and `something` because those are in `$fillable` and `else` won't be filled because it's not, but you can always do something like this:

```
$model = new Model($data);
$model->else = 'bar';
$model->save();
```

so you can set here `else` property value even if it's not inside `$fillable` but you need to access it like normal property.

Comment: So I can just pass the data as an argument of the model instantiation just like that?

Comment: @AuroraSchmidt Yes you can, but only fillable arguments should be filled and then you can fill non-fillable ones and finally save the model

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks for your advice. :)